# Laravel get header and footer to the content

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am new to laravel and i am trying to import my project into laravel.
I have been working with a header.php and a footer.php.
This two files will be loaded on every page.

How can i do this on Laravel?
I got everything about the view, controller and Models. My Controller is returnning

```
return view('main');
```

How can i also give the

```
view('header');
view('main');
view('footer');
```

And  i dont want to write this in every controller. Is there a way to pass it to the routes.php and is always loads the header, the given content and footer?

Comment: Within your main view you will extend other views and sections.  Give the docs a look.  Also many good quick tutorials on laracast.com.  https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#extending-a-layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a main layout where you put the header and footer in, and extend that layout in your other views.

Watch this series, takes about 3 hours and saves tens of hours of searching Google and the docs: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch

Comment: Sounds good. The point is: i have no idea how to make a main layout. But i think its better for me to watch this serien cause i am sure i will have a lot of questions. THX hope it helps after the 3h